# C++: memory issue when I delete a pointer created by new

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, delete-operator

I'm a little bit confused by the following code

```
int main()
{
    int* a = new int{12};
    int* b = new int;

    b = a;
    delete a;

    delete b;

    return 0;
}
```

The code returns an error that

```
a.out(27538,0x10ade7e00) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f8c18504160: pointer being freed was not allocated
a.out(27538,0x10ade7e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

My question is that, when I delete the a, does it automatically delete b? What is the mechanism here, I'm a little bit getting lost.

Comment: You delete one pointer twice and leak the other.

Comment: Both `a` and `b` point to the same memory.  Deleting both causes you to delete  the same memory block 2 times which is undefined behavior. You also leaked the memory  that `b` originally pointed to. There is no way to delete that because the address was thrown away in the `b = a;` assignment.

Comment: You are making the mistake of looking at the variable *name* instead of looking at the variable *value*.  If you debugged the code, you would see that after those calls to `new`, both `a` and `b` have different values.  It is those values that matter, not the name.  When you issued the `delete` call, you are deleting the same value twice since you assigned the value of `a` to `b`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
b = a;    // here the int that b pointed at "leaks" (you have no way of deleting it)

delete a; // here "a" is deleted first

delete b; // here "a" is deleted a second time (undefined behavior)
```

When you assign the value of `a` to `b`, the value (address if you will) `b` previously contained, is forgotten. Both `a` and `b` then points at the same object. You then lost all possibilities to `delete` the original object `b` pointed at. When you then `delete b` you in fact try deleting `a` a second time.

Comment: I'd say that `b = a;` is the line where "b" leaks.

Comment: @eerorika I can buy that. I choose "lost"  but I it's probably more correct to say "leak" directly there.

Answer (score 2):

Let's walk through the code line by line.

```
int* a = new int{12};
```

This creates a new variable called `a` of type `int*` and initializes it to point to a newly-allocated integer assigned the value 12.

```
int* b = new int;
```

This creates a new variable called `b` of type `int*` and initializes it to point to a newly-allocated integer.

```
b = a;
```

This changes `b`'s value to point to `a`. The value returned in the second call to `new` is now lost and that memory is leaked since it is no longer possible to pass it to `delete`.

```
delete a;
```

This deletes the object `a` points to, the one allocated first.

```
delete b;
```

Oops, this tries to delete the object `b` points to, but `b` doesn't point to any object that currently exists. The one allocated first was just deleted and no pointer to the second one exists. So this is a bug.

I suspect you are thinking that `delete a;` deletes `a`. It does not. It deletes whatever object `a` points to and requires that `a` be a pointer and point to a valid object that was allocated with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a pointer, all pointers, references, iterators etc. pointing to the destroyed object are invalidated. Because of the assignment `b = a`, b points to the same object as a does, so when a is deleted, b becomes invalid. Deleting an invalid pointer has undefined behaviour.

Note that `b = a` makes it impossible to delete the allocation that b previously pointed at. This is called a memory leak.